Driving a P-channel MOSFET with high voltage input
I designed a buck converter as an MPPT charger using high side switching.  It seems the signal on the gate of the MOSFET good. If a solar panel with low voltage like solar MPPT 18volt there isn't a problem
but I want to use a 39V MPPT solar panel with open terminal voltage 45V
I used four IRF4950 P-channel MOSFETs. The problem is with D1, 15V protection Zener.  It becomes very hot and burned and most of the components were damaged.  The second problem is with R6 it becomes so, so hot.
Any suggestion on how to drive the gate and limit the voltage so it does not exceed Vgs?


For such high voltage (40V) I would consider optocoupler+small isolated power supply (12V). Or use buck   version with N-ch on low-side.


Any suggestion on how to drive the gate and limit the voltage so it
does not exceed Vgs?

Try these modifications first: -


R6 was 10 Ω and would have been the main reason why it and the Zener got so warm
The added 10 kΩ discharges the gate-source should the push-pull driver become inactive

More than anything, you should use a simulator and simulate this circuit.

Since you are employing a push-pull stage to drive the gate, which is presumably intended to overcome a few nanofarads of gate capacitance, then any resistance between the push-pull output and the gate is counterproductive, and ideally you would want to keep R6 as small as possible.
However, a low R6 is going to draw a lot of current through D1 when the push-pull output is lower than 15V or so, which is why D1 heats up.
Perhaps, then, the solution is to constrain that push-pull output potential at the input instead. Here I moved the zener diode to clamp the bases of the push-pull pair:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Interesting.  Should work, but need to be careful with power dissipation in Q1.  This will be set by max voltage appearing at IN, R3, and Vcc.  Q1 collector current will need to be at least the current in R2 (15V/ 2k ~7.5mA) plus a margin to ensure D1 is conducting.   If IN is +5V, then Q1 Ic about 7.6mA (calc'd assuming Vbe=0.7V and V across R1 is about 0.73V by assuming beta=100).  Might be marginal, so suggest reducing R1 to about 1k.  For Q3 Ic=10mA, Q3 power will be ~250mW ((40V-15V) x 10mA).  Cheers.

i added Zener diode like you suggested, and tested emitter out signal without connection to MOSFET gate, all ok, but after i connected gate to emitter, tip42c PNP channel transistor burned with bomb :)

I would suggest starting again with a completely new design; the problem is driving a high-side switch which is difficult to do.  As part of a new design, I would consider using a power circuit where the gate driver is ground-referenced, such as a boost converter, or a buck converter where the load output is referenced to the positive of the input voltage.
Alternatively, to remain with your existing power circuit (buck converter with load referenced to 0V) then I would consider using a chip that is specifically designed either with the high-side power switch already included, or able to drive an external high-side switch (where the gate must go above the input voltage).  There are many such chips available, here is one example:
TI, TPS54360B-Q1
https://www.ti.com/product/TPS54360B-Q1
However, if you want to persist with this circuit, then here are some problems you should be aware of:-

Why are two MOSFETs connected in series?  The indicated MOSFET used, IRF4950, has a voltage rating of -55V, which means just one (1) would be OK for an input voltage of 45V (PV module maximum open terminal voltage), provided that circuit layout is tight so that any over-shoot on the MOSFET voltage waveform is limited.  I suggest removing the MOSFET drawn closest to the 40V supply , replacing it with a short-circuit, and adding a capacitor at the input of your converter.

R6: the value of 10Ω is far too small (low resistance value), causing too much current to flow in it, and also D1 and Q2 (when voltage at Q2 base was close to 0V).  This probably was the cause of D1 failing and R6 running hot.   Suggest changing R6 to 1kΩ or perhaps 2.2kΩ, but also make sure these can handle the power: suggest using 1W rated resistors for these (or a combination of 1/4W resistors to make up the correct R value and handle the required power).  There is a balancing act here: increasing R6 will reduce power dissipation in it (& D1, Q2) but will also slow down the switching transition from OFF to ON, which could increase power loss in the main MOSFETs (and possibly the inductor-current free-wheeling diode).

Put a 10kΩ resistor directly across MOSFET gate-source (as shown by the answer by @Andy aka).

R10 (2kΩ) also needs to be capable of high power, I would use a 1-watt resistor here also.

What is the voltage at the node marked "PIC PULS 22KHZ"?  Is it a digital pulse?  What is the voltage when it is (a) low (MOSFET OFF), and (b) high (MOSFET ON)?  In regards to this, the 470Ω resistor in the emitter of Q3 needs to be carefully selected, since it will have a very significant impact on the MOSFET gate-drive.
If the resistance is too high (compared with the voltage at "PIC PULS 22KHZ" when HI), then there will not be enough current in R10 to drive the voltage at Q2 base sufficiently low to turn on the MOSFET correctly.  This may cause it to switch slowly and/or have high power dissipation when ON.
If the resistance is too low, then Q3 (which is the TIP41C driving Q1 & Q2 - and please draw your schematic with all components identified) may be saturated when turned ON which causes it to switch off slowly, which will cause a delay in the turn-off of the main MOSFET.


